# Is there a way to check if user has a specific item in quick.db

Tags: node.js, database, discord.js, quick.db

I use `db.push(message.author.id), "item"` for doing this.

This is for making a game but I want it to not running the code if the user does not own that specific item.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `db.has(message.author.id + '.items.weapons')` for examlple

You can see more in the [npm website](https://www.npmjs.com/package/quick.db)

What you did :

```js
// Pushing an element to an array (that doesn't exist yet) in an object:
db.push(message.author.id + '.items', 'Sword')
// -> { items: ['Sword'] }
```

And what you should do to see if the element exists

```js
db.has(message.author.id + '.items')
```

Comment: try like this maybe : `if(db.has(message.author.id + '.items')) message.channel.send('You do have items ! Here are they : ${db.get(message.author.id + '.items')).join(' - ')` And if it didn't work please give me what you want so i can be specific ^^

Comment: Oh i didn't want to do that what i want is like 

`let item = db.has(message.author.id, desc) if(item) {a long long code here}` (desc = `${itemName}\n ${itemCat} - ${sellPrice}`)
This code doesn't work

Comment: hmm.. seems like i need a little bit more. add me as a friend so i can explain u better ^^' If you can here is my tag : ♫ ฅ^✯-✯^ฅ ♪#3526

Comment: epic, now everything is fixed uvu